# iPhone 3Gs turns on and off itself when being charged

Tags: iphone

My iPhone 3Gs turns off and on itself, again and again when I charge it, then it shows the battery sign but does not start. It all started happening after I updated my iOS. What should I do? How should I make sure that my data on my iPhone is not erased?

Comment: This happened with my iPhone when a charging cord was going bad.  After switching to another cord, my iPhone charging is now as expected.

Comment: no this is not the reason because i have tried different chargers on diffrent places, it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

after you updated did you restore from a backup or did you set it up as a new iPhone?  To be honest it sounds like your iPhone may have water/physical damage.

Comment: no it is not physically damaged, actually in setting it was showing that there is need to update so i choose updating opption then the download continued for 2 or 3 hour and after that when i saw it was blinking with apple logo.

Comment: m worried aout all my data that was in iphone, i dont wanna lose it:(

Answer (score -1):

Change your battery this method will work

Comment: How do you change the battery?